Cors Issues - Nextjs and wasm scripts
I am trying to rewrite deployed Wasm app to nextjs route. Actually I have tried different approaches, but it always fails.
Here's probably the simplest app I wanted to rewrite.
Here's the entry point:
use axum::Router;
use tower_http::services::{ServeDir, ServeFile};
use tower_http::cors::{Any, CorsLayer};

#[shuttle_runtime::main]
async fn main() -> shuttle_axum::ShuttleAxum {
    let layer = CorsLayer::new().allow_headers(Any);
    let router = Router::new().nest_service(
        "/",
        ServeDir::new("dist").not_found_service(ServeFile::new("dist/index.html")),
    ).layer(layer);
    Ok(router.into())
}

dist/index.html:
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="720" cursor="auto"></canvas>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" type="module">
        import init from "https://bevy-game.shuttleapp.rs/game.js"
        init()
    </script>
</body>

next.config.js:
const getCorsHeaders = () => {
  const headers = {};

  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] =
    "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] =
    "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization";

  return Object.entries(headers).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
};

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/wasm-test',
        destination: `https://prismatic-shortbread-d520b8.netlify.app`,
      },
      {
        source: '/wasm-test/:path*',
        destination: `https://prismatic-shortbread-d520b8.netlify.app/:path*`,
      },
      {
        source: '/wasm-shuttle',
        destination: `https://bevy-game.shuttleapp.rs`,
      },
      {
        source: '/wasm-shuttle/:path*',
        destination: `https://bevy-game.shuttleapp.rs/:path*`,
      }
    ]
  },
  headers: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/wasm-test",
        headers: getCorsHeaders(),
      },
      {
        source: "/wasm-test/:path*",
        headers: getCorsHeaders(),
      },
      {
        source: "/wasm-shuttle",
        headers: getCorsHeaders(),
      },
      {
        source: "/wasm-shuttle/:path*",
        headers: getCorsHeaders(),
      },
    ];
  },
  ...

Ofcourse, both routes wasm-test(netlify) and wasm-shuttle(shuttle.rs), have same problem. But the files are connected to wasm-test route.
The error:
wasm-shuttle:1 Access to script at 'https://bevy-game.shuttleapp.rs/game.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


The CorsLayer is not permissive by default (i.e. no origins allowed, no methods allowed, ...); you'll need to configure all the .allow_* functions or use CorsLayer::permissive().

Thanks @kmdreko, it's working. Now I just need to change import paths to absolute for assets, and it should be working.
